# Calculation outputs NaN on website, works in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, math, nan

I am trying to calculate the percentage of two dollar values on a page. I've got the code working in jsFiddle, but whenever I attempt to implement it on my website the code outputs NaN, so I know there must be some issue with my effort to convert the dollar amount to a number I can work with. I don't believe my scripts are conflicting, as I do not receive any errors in the console.

http://jsfiddle.net/f9rGj/

I've highlighted the two numbers I'm trying to calculate in red.

```
var price1 = $('.Value em.ProductPrice strike').text();
var price2 = $('.YouSave .YouSaveAmount').text();

var number1 = Number(price1.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
var number2 = Number(price2.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));

var savings = (Math.floor((number2 / number1) * 100));

$('#savepercent').text(savings);
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why this might be spitting out NaN? Maybe I need to try converting the dollar amount some other way?

Thanks to feedback I received, I was able to get this working on my site.

**Working code:**

```
var price1 = $('.Value em.ProductPrice strike').text();
var price2 = $('.YouSave .YouSaveAmount').text();


var number1 = parseInt(price1.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
var number2 = parseInt(price2.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));

var savings = (Math.floor((number2 / number1) * 100));

$('#savepercent').text(savings);
```

Comment: If it works in jsfiddle, there's something else wrong. You should remove code from your website until it works, or just use `console.log` to see the intermediate values.

Comment: Use the F12 debugger in Chrome etc to inspect your code, breakpoint and view values etc. Debugging is all about feedback and decent tools make it so much easier.

Comment: Learn to use the step debugger in your Browser! Have you even tried using `alert()` or `console.log()` to see what `number1` and `number2` are being set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use the correct String to Number conversion function:

[Number.parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat)

> The Number.parseFloat() method parses a string argument and returns a
> floating point number. This method behaves identical to the global
> function parseFloat and is part of ECMAScript 6 (its purpose is
> modularization of globals).

or

[Number.parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt)

> The Number.parseInt() method parses a string argument and returns an
> integer of the specified radix or base. This method behaves identical
> to the global function parseInt and is part of ECMAScript 6 (it's
> purpose is modularization of globals).

#### Know your RegEx

You should use `\D` which means `Any non-digit` instead of trying to do it yourself.

`\[^\D\.\,\]` will match any Non-Digits and the `.` or the `,` which is used outside the US for a delimiter instead of the `,`. See this [link](http://regex101.com/r/mR8wM3).

Comment: All true, but it is coerced to a number (and the JSFiddle does work)

Comment: I've figured it out, thanks Jarrod! I've updated my question with the code I got working.